# WSO2: ELB 2.0.3 and ESB 4.7/4.8M: unable to deserialize message

Tags: wso2, deserialization, load-balancing, esb

I guess there is a version issue between the tribes used by the ELB 2.0.3  (tribes version 028) and the tribes used by ESB 4.7.0 or 4.8.0M1 (tribes version 032) which lead to deserialization issue of org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl during the JOIN process:

```
ERROR {org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.Axis2GroupChannel} - Unable to deserialize message:ClusterData[src=org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[
```

If I use ELB 2.0.3 with ESB 4.6.0 (tribes 028), it works like a charm.
Is there a newest (and compliant) version of ELB available ?

Thanks

Dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ELB 2.0.3 should work well with Carbon 4.0.x and Carbon 4.1.x based products.

Check [WSO2 Release Matrix](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/) for more information about the Carbon version of each product.

Carbon 4.2.0 introduces Hazelcast based clustering and the compatible ELB product version is 2.1.0, which will be released in next few days.

ESB 4.8.0 is also based on Carbon 4.2.0 and therefore you will need ELB 2.1.0 to setup a cluster.

The release candidate builds are announced in [dev mailing list](http://wso2.com/mail/) and you should be able to download ELB 2.1.0 RC.

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait till the 2.1.0 version then.

Comment: That's great. Please find the latest ELB 2.1.0 pack here http://wso2.markmail.org/search/list:org.wso2.dev#query:list%3Aorg.wso2.dev+page:1+mid:lmbzdtojzwsgrgd7+state:results

Comment: OK, thanks; will test it w/4.8.0M2. Which clustering implementation should we use ? Hazelcast (the 'new' default one) or Tribes (which still exists) ?

Comment: Please use default clustering implementation. i.e. Hazelcast for Carbon 4.2.0 based products